# visualforce list button not working in Napili Community

Tags: visualforce, community, lightning-experience, napili, list-button

Visualforce list button is working in lightning experience whereas the same button is not working in Napili Community.I have enabled **Available for Lightning Experience, Salesforce1, and Lightning Communities** on Visualforce page settings and also added a visualforce page to Community Profile.

List Button shows up in Community but nothing happens on click on list button and no debug logs for community user.

I do see below error on console.

[image]

Comment: any console errors? or do you see popupblockers blocking content? did you check object crud related to the button's object?

Comment: @rao. I just found from Salesforce help. Visualforce List buttons buttons are not supported in communities. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_use_visualforce.htm&type=0

Comment: Good to know, as far as console error that you pointed, its a logo that is not loading and no big deal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visualforce list buttons are not supported in Communities.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_use_visualforce.htm&type=0

[image]

Comment: I am facing same issue with list buttons in Community. How did you end up doing it please?