# Visualforce custom list button not working in Napili Community

Tags: community, list-button

I have created a custom list button with visual force page and it is working in Salesforce console. The button is not responding in Napili community as it doesn't do any action after clicking it. Below thread has same question with answer saying visualforce custom list buttons are not supported in Communities but any work around is appreciated.

[visualforce list button not working in Napili Community](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195745/visualforce-list-button-not-working-in-napili-community)

PS: I couldn't comment on that thread as I do not have reputations.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_use_visualforce.htm&type=0

Looks like VF list buttons are not supported in lightning communities